# Magento 2 - Correct way of Module Installation

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

Trying to install sample module in Magento 2 from [this](https://github.com/darshanb87/magento2-extension-example). Below is the module structure `app/code/NameSpace/Module/`

[image: module image]

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magentostudy_News" setup_version="0.0.1" schema_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magentostudy/module-news",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-store": "100.0.0",
        "magento/module-email": "100.0.0",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magentostudy\\News\\": ""
        }
    }
    }
```

**Registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magentostudy_News',
    __DIR__
);
```

Executing below command to enable module

```
php ./bin/magento module:enable Magentostudy_News
```

It says `there are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.` Also on frontend it throws below exception. I am using composer but not github.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source class "\Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\Setup" for "Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\SetupFactory" generation does not exist.'`

**CODE EDIT**

Added `Setup` folder with file `InstallSchema.php` which includes below code

```
    <?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 */

/* @var $installer \Magento\Setup\Module\SetupModule */

namespace Magentostudy\News\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Creating table magentostudy_news
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
    $installer->getTable('magentostudy_news')
)->addColumn(
    'news_id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
    'Entity Id'
)->addColumn(
    'title',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    255,
    ['nullable' => true],
    'News Title'
)->addColumn(
    'author',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    255,
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'Author'
)->addColumn(
    'content',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    '2M',
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'Content'
)->addColumn(
    'image',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    null,
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'News image media path'
)->addColumn(
    'created_at',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    null,
    ['nullable' => false],
    'Created At'
)->addColumn(
    'published_at',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATE,
    null,
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'World publish date'
)->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName(
        'magentostudy_news',
        ['published_at'],
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
    ),
    ['published_at'],
    ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX]
)->setComment(
    'News item'
);
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->endSetup();
```

1. What is the correct way to install **Magento 2** modules ?
2. Any crucial step I missed ?

Reference URL : http://mageinferno.com/blog/setting-up-magento-2-module-right-way-composer-packagist

Comment: are you trying with stable release module version?

Comment: Module reference - https://github.com/darshanb87/magento2-extension-example

Comment: Please add reference of registration.php in module's composer.json > its autoload section.

Comment: You can check example from here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is two correct in your module you need to try

1 : correct your **composer.json**

here is basic example :

```
{
"name": "magentostudy/module-news",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/module-store": "100.0.0",
    "magento/module-email": "100.0.0",
    "magento/module-ui": "100.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.0"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "0.0.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Magentostudy\\News\\": ""
    }
}
```

}

2 :

In your Directory there is one Folder is Missing

Called **Setup** instead of **sql**

for more Details read these modules :

https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples

Out the Setup File name should be : InstallSchema.php

code something like :

```
namespace Magentostudy\News\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();
        $table  = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('test_helloworld'))
            ->addColumn(
                'id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'Id'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'label',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['default' => null, 'nullable' => false],
                'Name'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'value',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                ['default' => null, 'nullable' => false],
                'Stores'
            );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

try to edit your modules.xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magentostudy_News" setup_version="0.0.1">

    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. See my Code Edit as you instructed. What next  I am supposed to do after updating above ? Am I still missing out something ?

Comment: It Depends on what error you are facing now but i can help you more in this if you share information in details with me and mark my answer as helpful

Comment: I have shared all the details in my question, let me know if you want any more details. I ll mark it accepted once am I am able  to install the module. The exception is `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source class "\Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\Setup" for "Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\SetupFactory" generation does not exist.'`

Comment: remove the sql and data folder as well

Comment: Did everything as said above. How do I know if its correctly installed ? Do I need to run any command as its still throwing same error

Comment: i updated my answer like this

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magentostudy_News" setup_version="0.0.1">

    </module>
</config>

and try to delete the sql and data folder from your module

Comment: and try this php magento setup:upgrade and send me again files that you updated as well as screen shot of your module root